# Causing one tag to click another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently installed an npm package and the component being exported from it was set in such a way that one must click the component and hold the mouse button in other for it to work e.g like the record audio button on WhatsApp. Now I would like this button to be activated by click instead. Is there any possible way for me to do this?

Well here is some the code hope it helps

```
import Recorder from 'react-mp3-recorder'

class{
...
render(){
...
return(
<Recorder
        onRecordingComplete={this._onRecordingComplete}
        onRecordingError={this._onRecordingError}
    >
```

Then in the github repo of the package I opened the index file

```
 return (
      <div
        className={classNames(styles.container, className)}
        {...rest}
      >
        <div
          className={styles.button}
          onMouseDown={this._onMouseDown}
          onMouseUp={this._onMouseUp}
        >
          <img src={micIcon} width={24} height={24} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  _cleanup() {
    if (this._recorder) {
      this._recorder.stopRecording()
      this._recorder.close()
      delete this._recorder
    }
  }

  _onMouseDown = () => {
    const {
      recorderParams
    } = this.props

    this._cleanup()

    this._recorder = new vmsg.Recorder({
      wasmURL,
      shimURL,
      ...recorderParams
    })

    this._recorder.init()
      .then(() => {
        this._recorder.startRecording()
        this.setState({ isRecording: true })
      })
      .catch((err) => this.props.onRecordingError(err))
  }

  _onMouseUp = () => {
    if (this._recorder) {
      this._recorder.stopRecording()
        .then((blob) => this.props.onRecordingComplete(blob))
        .catch((err) => this.props.onRecordingError(err))
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes, somehow thats possible.

Comment: `an npm package`  It might help if you tell us..

Comment: react-mp3-recorder

Comment: Provide some code snippet for this question.

Comment: @AvinashMahlawat just added what seemed relevant